# Removing item from list Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anyone know how to remove an `item` from the `list` in the code below if the `item.profit` is less than 1?

Splice doesn't seem to work.

Let's say that this returns something like:

```
item 1, profit = 10
item 2, profit = 5
item 3, profit = -3
item 4, profit = 5
item 5, profit = -2
```

I'm trying to end up with the list as:

```
item 1, profit = 10
item 2, profit = 5
item 3, profit = 5

var i = 0;
async.forEach(list, function (item, callback) {

    var url = 'http://www.website.com';
    request(url, function (err, response, html) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            /// some code before....

            item.profit = (some calculation here);

            if (item.profit < 1) {
                console.log("Profit less than 1, so removing from list...");
                list.splice(i, 1); // This doesn't seem to work
            }

            // some code after...

        }
        callback();
    });
}, function (err) { //This is the final callback
    callback(err, list);
});
```

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: does not seem you are changing your i variable

Comment: does the console log fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that async.forEach() processes items in parallel.  Therefore, modifying the entries of the original list is a problem.  You might want to save all wanted entries in a new list.  Here is the code:

```
var i = 0, 
    newList = [];
async.eachSeries(list, function (item, callback) {  // <<<<< done is series to keep
                                                    // the same order as the original
                                                    // list, if you don't care about
                                                    // the order, then use
                                                    // async.each()

  var url = 'http://www.website.com';
  request(url, function (err, response, html) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        /// some code before....

        item.profit = (some calculation here);

        if (item.profit > 0) {
            newList.push(item);
        }

        // some code after...

    }
    callback();
  });
}, function (err) { //This is the final callback
  callback(err, newList);
});
```

Comment: parallel means async is processing multiple items of the list at the same time.  For example list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9], sync.each is processing entries list[0], list[1], ..., at the same time instead of waiting for list[0] to finish before processing list[1] (which is called "in series")

Comment: You mean the callback returns a promise?

Comment: Yes, node.js is single threaded but that doesn't mean it can only process 1 item until it's done before doing something else... think of it as 1 person doing multiple tasks by switching tasks back and fore instead of completing 1 task and then starting another

Comment: Ben - brilliant answer and explanations. Thanks so much. I wasted hours trying to get this working and the answer was so obvious! :-)